# How the interface builder has been designed for the following type of application with splitviewcontroller?

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I am posting a link.  Can anybody please tell me that how the interface builder has been designed for this type of application?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iorder-for-ipad/id385298425?mt=8

On this link, please look for the fourth image in the "Ipad Screenshots" section. The image on which a splitviewcontroller is taken and on the detailViewController the details of "Green Valley Inc." are displayed.

Comment: I am using Monotouch and not Xcode. Thanks

Comment: Anyways, Hey Joe! do u know how should be the interface builder for this type of application?

Comment: Bear in mind that not every app was designed in IB.

Comment: Ok. But can anybody then tell me that how the controls were arranged?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a clear splitviewController to me, so add one of those, programmaticly or via IB.
or whatever program u use.
Also it is the 5th screenshot ^_-
But, that's a standard splitView, hope that gets u going!
Download standard MultipleViews or so from developer.apple.com, which will set u on the way

Comment: How can i add a search bar on the Master table view controller. On the Master Table View Controller we cannot see a tableview but it is there. I know how to add a search bar on the TableView but i dont know that how to add a search bar on TableViewController.

Comment: Please try taking a Splitviewcontroller and try adding a serach bar on the table view controller. If u succeed in it ten plz let me know. Thanks